# crystal reports fill with lines

Tags: crystal-reports

I am making a report for a workorder for our workplace. The report prints the header of the order (order number, customer details etc.) Then it prints the text rows containing instructions what needs to be done. Mostly 1-10 lines.

After the instructions, I would like to have the page filled with empty lines where our mechanics can fill in their activities. I do not want the report to be more then one page. So, the more instructions, the less lines the report gets at the end.

I have searched several forums, but cannot find a good solution. Any help would be appreciated. I am using CR 2008.

Regards, Arno

Comment: What do you require exactly?  How to fill with lines or where to fill the files

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add every "empty line" within a separate footer section, toggle section visibility depending on TotalRowCount (e.g. footer section A is only visible if TotalRowCount < 10, footer section B is visible if Rowcount < 9, etc.)