# Create section dynamically within a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement where i need to create a section on crystal report multiple times based on a value coming from an XML. I am not using Java or C#. i need to do this within Crystal report.

Version = Crystal Report 2016

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. #1 Please provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with snippets of relevant code (HTML,CSS,etc.) so we can better help you thank you. #2 Please identify a specific and unique question in your post.

Comment: #1 . This is my XML 
<LetterData>
  <ID>1234</ID>
  <TemplateType>1</TemplateType>
  <Inserts>
     <NumberofLabels>10</NumberofLabels>
  </Inserts>
  </LetterData>


#2  I am looking to dynamically create detail section based on NumberofLabels values. In this example i am looking for 10 details section to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum number of labels is not too high, you could

- prepare as much detail sections as will be needed at max,
- and control the visibility of each detail section according to your value in "NumberOfLabels"

as shown for MaxRowCount in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757988/2336282).